# For the purpose of the Detect Magic and Identify spells, is a magic item that is currently out of power still treated as a magic item?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, magic

If a magic item runs on "Magic Batteries", when the item is out of power, would it be treated as a magic item for the purpose of the *identify* and *detect magic* spells?

For example, I have a mirror that shows through illusions. It has crystals around it that are destroyed as you used it; you can replace the crystals for more uses when it has no crystals. Would it still be treated as a magic item that is detectable by the *identify*/*detect magic* spells?

Would the same be true for items with charges that recharge at dawn? If the item has 0 charges and is not dawn yet, would it be still be treated as a magic item?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Yes, it is still magical

On the basis that [things do only what they say](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret), a magical item remains magical unless there is a rule stating otherwise.

The rules call out several cases where magic items do lose their magic. Here's a sampling (all citations from *Dungeon Master's Guide*):

> Once used, a consumable item loses its magic. *(pg. 141)*

> Once it hits a target, the ammunition is no longer magical. *(pg. 150)*

> Once an arrow of slaying deals its extra damage to a creature, it becomes a nonmagical arrow. *(pg. 152)*

> Doing so ends that pellet's magic. *(pg. 166)*

> If a magic bead is removed from the necklace, that bead loses its magic. *(pg. 182)*

> On a 1, the staff becomes a nonmagical quarterstaff. *(pg. 201)*

However, many items that can regain their abilities **do not** include this wording:

> The bowl can't be used this way again until the next dawn. *(p.g 156)*

> The cube starts with 36 charges, and it regains 1d20 expended charges daily at dawn. [...] If the cube has insufficient charges remaining, nothing happens. *(pg. 156–160)*

> On a 1, the staff retains its +2 bonus to attack and damage roll but loses all other properties. On a 20, the staff regains 1d8 + 2 charges. *(pg. 202)*

Many items also call out circumstances under which they are destroyed, in which case there is no longer an item to be magical.

It sounds like your mirror is a homebrew item, in which case the DM is welcome to add a rule stating that the item is nonmagical when without crystals, but this would be a specific exception, not a general rule.

Comment: Good last paragraph. Homebrew problems require homebrew solutions.